# How write inline if condition inside pie series in pie chart?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flex4.5

Im trying to change colour according to Label value in pie series.Im trying to write a inline if condition inside pie series like this

```
<mx:PieSeries
                    id="s1"
                    field="Value" 
                    nameField="Label" 
                    color="{'Value'='Other'?0xd8d8d8:colorArr}">                

</mx:PieSeries>
```

this is my data source to pie chart.data source length is not fixed. it will change dynamically.so i cant passs colour array by hard coding particular colour to other label field.Thats why im tying to write if condition inside pie series.

This is a sample data source

```
var expenses:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
                {Label:"Taxes", Value:1001},
                {Label:"Rent", Value:1005},
                {Label:"Bills", Value:1008},
                {Label:"Car", Value:1009},
                {Label:"Gas", Value:1020},
                {Label:"Food", Value:1015},
                {Label:"Other", Value:1080}  
            ]);
```

This is my colour array

```
private var colorArr:Array = new Array(
            "0x1ad6ef",
            "0xee816d",
            "0xfdd849",
            "0xff9e5d",
            "0xa4c286",
            "0xca6353",
            "0xd69b99",
            "0xe67976", 
            "0xfe9ae3",
            "0x6965b8", 
            "0xfebf9a",
            "0xfeb548"
        );
```

Is this possible guys ?

Comment: change color fill based on the label? how do you assign each color to label? btw you are better off creating a function and calling it inline.

Comment: do You need to color the label or the pie pieces?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
 color="{'Value'=='Other'?0xd8d8d8:0xffffff}"
```

Comment: thank you for your reply.i made a mistake.so i corrected that one.if Label field eqauls to "Other" particular colour must assign.else must assign predefined colour array to pie series.